# how to understand the dependency on mvvm?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I know that the mvvm model is seperated to 3 elementes, model viewmodel view. but studying mvvm with my application dev, I thought there is really no dependency? here is my code on MainActivity.
Do I misunderstand the mvvm or misuse? I think the 
`"binding.user=mainViewModel.getIndexList().value"` is dependency. I misuse this code? or the code is right but I misunderstand?

```
mainViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
mainViewModel.init("myname")
mainViewModel.getIndexList().observe(this, Observer<UserModel>(){
        t->
    if(mainViewModel.getIndexList().value==null){
        Log.d("TAG","NULL");
    }else{
        Log.d("TAG","SUCCESS");
        binding.user=mainViewModel.getIndexList().value
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

See first understand what you are observing here you are trying to observe the UserModel
as i can see so in return you will  get UserviewModel.

Here in below code t is your UserModel value you can directly access it.

```
mainViewModel.getIndexList().observe(this, Observer<UserModel>(){
    t->
if(t==null){
    Log.d("TAG","NULL");
}else{
    Log.d("TAG","SUCCESS");
    binding.user=t
}

 })
```

If you still have any doubt feel free to ask.Happy Coding!!!